# auto change to the next song after ended

Tags: javascript

I want to auto to play next song after ended until last song. currently this my code.

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audio" src="Music/Inuyasha - Dearest ~Instrumental~.mp3" controls></audio>
<div class="btn" name="Music/Inuyasha - Dearest ~Instrumental~.mp3"></div><br>
<div class="btn" name="Music/Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas -  Just Awake.mp3"></div><br>
<div class="btn" name="Music/Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas - How Old You Are Never Forget Your Dream.mp3"></div><br>
<div class="btn" name="Music/Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas - Short but Seems Long time of our Life Lyrics.mp3"></div><br>
<div class="btn" name="Music/My First Story - Calling You.mp3"></div><br>
<div class="btn" name="Music/My First Story - Bullet Radio.mp3"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

$() is document.getElementById(). i make it owns.

```
  // my codes is not JQuery but Pure JavaScript.

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for(i=0; i < btn.length; i++){

    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(v){
        $('audio').src = v.target.getAttribute('name');
        $('audio').play();
    }, false);

    //Above codes is not problem but bottom for auto to change next song after ended

    btn[i].index = i;

    $('audio').addEventListener('ended', function(){
        $('audio').src = btn[this.index+1].getAttribute('name');
        $('audio').play();
    }, false);
}
```

// my ended works is when song ended it will get current index array song then +1 the current index array and play it until last song. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn'),
    currentBtn = -1;

for(i=0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        // get current btn index
        currentBtn = Array.prototype.slice.call( btn ).indexOf(this);

        $('audio').btn[currentBtn].getAttribute('name');
        $('audio').play();
    }, false);
}

$('audio').addEventListener('ended', function() {
    // get next button index. if it was last one - repeat from first btn
    currentBtn++;
    if (currentBtn >= btn.length) {
      currentBtn = 0;
    }
    $('audio').src = btn[currentBtn].getAttribute('name');
    $('audio').play();
}, false);
```

Comment: i forgot to say $() is document.getElementById. i make it owns. its not JQuery api.

Comment: I don recommend you to use $ as you custom variable. If someone you want to use jQuery you will have problems. I updated code, so take a look to new solution - remember index of current button and increment it when song ended.

Comment: it keeps loop first song not to the next. by the way you know how to repack array to array again from loop? i want to save it in var a = [btn[i].getAttribute('name')]; so when i document.write(a[3]); i will return the 4rd value.

Comment: 1. what happens if you click at 2nd button and song ended? What the next song will play? 2. a[3] returns 4rd value cause array indexing starts with 0. To return 3rd element you need to use index=2.

Comment: your code if song ended. i will jump to last song. it not loop until last song. and my comment is new question to repack array to be array again after loop? i just ask new question here think link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776017/repack-array-to-be-array-again-after-loop?noredirect=1#comment38447440_24776017

Comment: is my code works correctly? if yes please mark question as solved. if not - tell me what is wrong?

Comment: no, as i say your code is lets say i play from 3 after ended it will jump to last song index 8. instead play 4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: It works fine for me. Use debug to understand why index is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it in pure JS using an event listener. I hope you find the code helpful. Update: added support for adding more songs easily

```
     <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<audio controls id="au" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="Airport Lounge.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>

<script> 
var c=0;
var songs = ["Airport Lounge.mp3", "Airport Lounge.mp3", "Airport Lounge.mp3"];

var a=document.getElementById("au");
a.addEventListener('ended', function(){

document.getElementById("au").src=songs[c]; 
a.load();  
console.log(c); 
c++;

if(c>=songs.length){
    c=0;
}

});

</script> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: thats for single song. my aims is list of song. look my HTML there're 5 and more song.

Comment: thats what i do now. i don't know why this.value is not work on loop. if try with single is work.

Comment: If you appreciated my help click the checkmark button by my answer. Is there anything else I can help with regarding this issue

Comment: you're code are doing manually. it will such a useless. would you repeat to type if your song 100? hahaha

Comment: Is it good now? I got rid or the switch case now it is easy to add 100 songs

Comment: Before you go to far look my code first. i'm using php to dump list of my song. and the player can get current index array if say i start from index array 3 then it will play from 3 to last song. thats way look my code first just fix a thing. make it simple. straigt-forward. i appreciated your help :)