# Repack array to be array again after loop

Tags: javascript

i want to repack array to be array again after loop. my code like this.

HTML

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Windows"><br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Linux">
```

Javascript

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
var a = [btn[i].value];

document.write(a.indexOf("Windows")); //return 0
}
```

above code it doesn't work. i want to repack btn.value to var a  then can be access by indexOf to return value index.

Comment: `document.write(a[1])` should be `document.write(a[0])`

Comment: i know if it document.write(a[0]). it will result 2 value. what i want is to make it to be seperate index. like a[0] windows. a[1] linux after loop. instead a[0] return windows linux. by the way how you can tag code in comment?. i press CTRL+K doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "repack"? Please explain in words how you want `a` to look like

Comment: @DavidSlavalia: Use backticks: `\`around code\``

Answer (score 0):

you're resetting a in your loop

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var a = [];
for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
   a.push(btn[i].value);

   console.log(a[i]);
}

document.write(a[a.indexOf("Windows")]);
```

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/janLy/4/

Comment: Still something important missing.

Comment: You are resetting as well, instead of ```a = btn[i].value;``` try ```a.push(btn[i].value);```

Comment: your code is dump all, just like var a =[btn[i].value]; document.write(a[0]);  return windows linux not different. what i want it to make seperate index access. like a[0] windows a[1] linux after loop.

Comment: you can acces it outside of the loop with document.write(a[0]); Or document.write(a[1]); @DavidSlavalia

Comment: i want use it inside loop. cause i need to find index array string using indexOf("Windows"); . i try using it outside a.indexOf("Windows"); return -1.

Comment: I remade the fiddle and rewrote my code to fit your description is this what you were looking for? @DavidSlavalia

Comment: this's my code http://jsfiddle.net/MSGHQ/1/ and thiss my main question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767380/auto-change-to-the-next-song-after-ended/24767686?noredirect=1#comment38447301_24767686

Answer (score 0):

the DOM method getElementsByClassName returns a type of pseudo-array called HTMLCollection. 
i think what you're asking is how to change the indexed values of btn.
To access array methods on btn, and to write new values to btn, convert btn to a true array:

```
btn = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('btn'), 0);
```

Comment: Looks like he wants to get the `.value`s, not the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

change the array index to 0 not 1. a[0]

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var a = [];
for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++)
 {
   a = [btn[i].value];
   document.write(a[0]);
 }
```

Other solution

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var a = [];
for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++)
 {
   a.push(btn[i].value);
   document.write(a[i]);
 }
```

Comment: your code is dump all value. what i want is seperate index access. like a[0] return windows. a[1] return linux. instead a[0] return windows linux.

Comment: Second solution works the exact way u mentioned . you can access like document.write(a[0]) oustside the for loop which return windows and document.write(a[1])  return linux.

Answer (score 0):

You are always replacing the `a` array. You have to do it like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn'),
    a = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  a.push(btn[i].value);
  console.log(a[i]);
}

document.write('The second value of a is: ' + a[1]);
```

Please note that if you use `document.write()` inside the loop, the content will be replaced with your text and the second button will not be available anymore.

Here is a demo: http://jqversion.com/#!/XwJIEUt